# Arrow function (Lambda function) with Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, lambda

I know little about lambda, and lambda expression is treated as a function. and we have lots of ways to do that.

This is my simple function on `TypeScript` file

```
 byPan(card1,card2){
    return card1.pan == card2.pan;
 }
```

which I am using in HTML file like

```
 <select [compareWith]="byPan" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="card">
     <option *ngFor="let cardInfo of cards" [ngValue]="cardInfo">{{cardInfo.pan}}</option>
 </select>
```

If I want to replace this function in lambda then I can write as follows.

```
var myFunc2 = (card1, card2) => { return card1.pan == card2.pan};
```

So my question is, Can I use this lambda function directly on any angular property like `compareWith` or something like?

```
 <select [compareWith]="(card1,card2)=> { return card1.pan == card2.pan}" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="card">
     <option *ngFor="let cardInfo of cards" [ngValue]="cardInfo">{{cardInfo.pan}}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: First of all, please read angular's documentation on what is and is not allowed inside a template. Second of all, that construct is not callled a lamda in Javascript, it is called arrow function

Comment: There is a GitHub ticket that kinda asks to support arrow functions: [14129](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14129).

Comment: Thanks @JacobvanLingen, I will track this issue.

Answer (score 5):

You can't just execute arrow function in template. Angular will accept only expressions that can bind with `component` or `directives`. So basically no, you can't use arrow function in template. It's the best to leave it as a method in your `component`.

However if you are looking on small expressions you can use `shorthand if` it could look like:

```
[compareWith]="card1.pan == card2.pan" // returns bool value
```

or

```
[compareWith]="card1.pan == card2.pan ? 'foo' : 'bar".
```

Comment: I guess that `[compareWith]="card1.pan == card2.pan"` won't do the thing that is the OP expects. compareWith input will be boolean value and not a function.

Comment: Of course it won't. but it can be workaround for it or he will have to change logic of app. There is always use of `eval` and pass stringified function but it's highly dangerous and really bad solution but it might do the trick

Comment: I guess If we write `[compareWith]="card1.pan == card2.pan"` then angular will try to find card1 & card2 in angular's Model objects, and it will always give us an `false`.

Answer (score 3):

Functions cannot be defined in templates, primarily because this would result in `eval` in JIT compilation mode. Using component templates to for things that primarily belongs to classes would result in poor quality code that is hard to maintain.

If a function has be defined, it should be defined as component class method. It can be either regular or arrow function.

Comment: I don't think defining 50 different simple id comparisons is very good for code quality either. If this is used responsibly, it would tidy up code a lot and save a lot of time